# Does there exist a build in function that will help append a new list to an existing defined list in python?

Tags: python

```
list = [ ["Eggs", "Milk", "Cheese"], [1, 2, 3, 4], ["A", "B" ] ]

newlist = []
appendThisList = []
for count in range(0, 13):
    appendThisList.append(count)

    if int(count) % 3 == 0:
        newlist.append(appendThisList)
        appendThisList.clear()

list.append(newlist)
print(list)
```

Output:

```
[['Eggs', 'Milk', 'Cheese'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B'], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```

expected:

```
[['Eggs', 'Milk', 'Cheese'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B'], [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,11,12] ]
```

Comment: Use `appendThisList = []` instead of `appendThisList.clear()`.

Comment: When you clear appendThisList, you're calling the list you added to newlist and telling it to erase itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here.

```py
   if int(count) % 3 == 0:
        newlist.append(appendThisList)
        appendThisList.clear()
```

Right code should be:

```py
   from copy import copy
   if int(count) % 3 == 0:
        newlist.append(copy(appendThisList))
        appendThisList.clear()
```

Explanation: You always add the same instance of the list `appendThisList` to the result. And when you clear it, it clears everywhere even after adding.

Proof:

```py
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[[]]
>>> a.append('1')
>>> b
[['1']]
>>> a.pop()
'1'
>>> b
[[]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two errors.
First you should start your range from 1, otherwise 0 will be added to your list.
Then as already mentioned by @mrvol, you're clearing the list you have freshly appended. You don't necessarily have to import copy though. Unpacking will do as well:

```
list = [ ["Eggs", "Milk", "Cheese"], [1, 2, 3, 4], ["A", "B" ] ]

newlist = []
appendThisList = []
for count in range(1, 13):
    appendThisList.append(count)

    if int(count) % 3 == 0:
        newlist += [[*appendThisList]]
        appendThisList.clear()

list.append(newlist)
print(list)
```

Output:

```
[['Eggs', 'Milk', 'Cheese'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B'], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```